# Any example for a C#-WebGis development on the basis of DotSpatial?

Tags: dotspatial

I already used DotSpatial in a few projects. It is fine for reading/writing shapefiles, clipping etc..

According to the DotSpatial documentation, it is possible, to create WebGis projects, but I wonder why I cannot find any on the Web? Also, I wasn't able to find any tutorial for it. On GitHub there is a sample project called DemoWeb (https://github.com/DotSpatial/DotSpatial/tree/master/Source/Examples/DemoWEB) but I wasn't able to get it running.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an AMAZING open-source, fully managed code implementation of a GIS engine for desktop, easily ported to mobile and web.

https://github.com/Opzet/SimpleMap

> It is a FOSS fully managed dot net core 5.0 codebase, It is compact
> and easy to use, a really nice GIS engine.
>
> I need some minor help with the Georeference function and the raster
> layer loader.
>
> Please download and try out the **working demos with a small
> footprint**
>
> This is a fully workable sample project on C# for Visual Studio 2019
>
> Sample demonstrates how You can use maps in your projects.
>
> You can download and run **SimpleMap.exe**. Or download and compile
> the source code.
>
> **Features**
>
> - All in one Winform control
> - **No un-managed Code & No Dependencies.**
> - Small code size
> - Lightweight
>
> **Rendering**
>
> - Fast image draw to screen via GDI+, written pure on C# without any direct mapping to WinApi.
> - Double buffering technology, all image changes draw into memory buffer and then changes apply to the screen.
>
> **Tile servers**
>
> Download map images from tile servers (e.g google).
>
> - Cache map tile on disk.
> - Download google image file cache to local storage.
> - Save google Maps as one image.
> - Base classes to draw any map layers.
>
> **Georeference Raster Images**  Work in progress Georeference image to create world file
>
> - Load raster image (pngw,bmpw,jpgw,tifw, etc) as geo referenced overlay
>
> **GIS Projection**
>
> - Projection of coordinate system through subclasses and operators.
> - Translate google coordinates to longitude and latitude.
> - Translate longitude and latitude to google coordinates.
> - Math operators support working with coordinates.
> - Spatial in-memory index with fast search by coordinates based on google map coordinate system.
> - Spatial index tuning.
> - Spatial index supported objects are: Point, Line, Rectangle, Polygon(partially supported).
>
> SimpleMap/ExampleForms/FrmMapDownloader.cs demonstrates how to
> download google map area as single image (GetFullMapThread function)
> or how to cache google map on local disk (DownloadThread function).
>
> SimpleMap/ExampleForms/Controls/MapCtl.cs demonstrates how to draw
> cached google map images to screen with custom objects as lines,
> bitmaps etc.
>
> It is absolutely free for use.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I lost quite a few hours navigating and finally found this:
https://github.com/DotSpatial/DotSpatial/issues/951

The developers themselves decided no longer to describe the DotSpatial libtrabies to be Web-compatible. They are perfect for Desktop GIS but the Web Components need to be updated. The text is from 2017 so I don't know whether a better version is available.

Comment: Please don't ask questions in Answers.